# "Error in x1[, 2] * pi : non-numeric argument to binary operator" in thin ( ) operation

Tags: r, modeling

I'm a beginner programmer and I've been working with RStudio for about four months now. As part of the code I am writing, I am trying to downscale species occurrence data using the thin() function from the "spThin" package. The process totally worked when I used it on my first dataset:

```
hyacinth.thinned <- thin(hyacinth.data.clean, lat.col = "decimallatitude", 
                         long.col = "decimallongitude", spec.col = "species", 
                         thin.par = 1, reps = 1, locs.thinned.list.return = TRUE, write.files = TRUE, 
                         max.files = 1, out.dir = "C:\\...", 
                         out.base = "hyacinth.thinned")
```

In the hyacinth.data.clean table there are 20 variables and not all are numeric, however, the columns that matter are.
When I tried to use it for my other datasets with the exact same code:

```
points.thin <- thin(pointlayer, lat.col = "Latitude", 
                         long.col = "Longitude", spec.col = "SciName", 
                         thin.par = 1, reps = 1, locs.thinned.list.return = TRUE, write.files = TRUE, 
                         max.files = 1, out.dir = "C:\\...", 
                         out.base = "points.thin")
```

it came out with the

> "Error in x1[, 2] * pi : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

message.

The difference between these datasets is that the first came from a occ_search from GBIF function while the second came from an import of a geopackage using "sf" package and st_read function. Both ended up leaving me with the same type of file so I'm not too sure what the difference would be. Maybe it is something to do with the geometry being derived from a "shape" column containing values like:

```
list(c(-84.1696071624756, -84.16428565979, -84.1651439666748, -84.1699504852295, -84.1696071624756, 30.4486736792876, 30.4477117627055, 30.4452699318254, 30.4451959359953, 30.4486736792876))
```

??

I'll paste my whole code down below and would appreciate any help- but please put it in relatively plain language for me as I am not good at this yet haha.

```
# load packages 
library(rgbif)
library(scrubr)
library(maps)
library(dplyr)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(dismo)
library(countrycode)
library(CoordinateCleaner)
library(ggplot2)
library(devtools)
library(spThin)

## download data from GBIF
species <- "Eichhornia crassipes"
hyacinth.search <- occ_search(scientificName = species, 
                              hasCoordinate = TRUE, 
                              hasGeospatialIssue = FALSE,
                              limit = 21000)

# needs to stay in this format until 'issues' have been dealt with
# to search for issues
hyacinth.search %>% 
  occ_issues(cdiv)
# to remove records with specific issues:
hyacinth.issues.clean <- hyacinth.search %>%
  occ_issues(-bri, -ccm, -cdiv, -cdout, -cdpi, -cdrepf, -cdreps,
             -cdumi, -conti, -cucdmis, -cum, -gdativ, -geodi, 
             -geodu, -iccos, -iddativ, -iddatunl, -indci, -mdativ, 
             -mdatunl, -osifbor, -osu, -preneglat, -preneglon, 
             -preswcd, -rdativ, -rdatm, -rdatunl, -typstativ, 
             -zerocd)

# keep the columns that matter for mapping and cleaning the occurrence data:   
hyacinth.data <- hyacinth.issues.clean$data[ , c("species", "decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude", 
                                                 "issues", "countryCode", "individualCount", 
                                                 "occurrenceStatus", "coordinateUncertaintyInMeters", 
                                                 "institutionCode", "gbifID", "references", "basisOfRecord", 
                                                 "year", "month", "day", "eventDate", "geodeticDatum", 
                                                 "datasetName", "scientificName", "catalogNumber")]

# Create/view map of raw data points 
wm <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="gray50")
ggplot()+ coord_fixed()+ wm +
  geom_point(data = hyacinth.data, aes(x = decimalLongitude, y = decimalLatitude),
             colour = "darkred", size = 0.5)+
  theme_bw()

## Clean records 
# remove records without coordinates (should not have been included in download but just in case)
# remove rows with N/A 
hyacinth.data <- hyacinth.data%>%
  filter(!is.na(decimalLongitude))%>%
  filter(!is.na(decimalLatitude))%>%
  filter(!is.na(countryCode))%>%
  filter(!is.na(occurrenceStatus))%>%
  filter(!is.na(coordinateUncertaintyInMeters))%>%
  filter(!is.na(institutionCode))%>%
  filter(!is.na(geodeticDatum))%>%
  filter(occurrenceStatus != "ABSENT") # removes all 'absent' records

# remove records pre-1970 and 2021
hyacinth.data <- hyacinth.data%>%
  filter(between(year, 1970, 2020))

## Clean using CoordinateCleaner
# convert country code from ISO2c to ISO3c (so coordinatecleaner can use it)
hyacinth.data$countryCode <-  countrycode(hyacinth.data$countryCode, 
                                          origin =  'iso2c', 
                                          destination = 'iso3c') # is this necessary?

# identify and remove flag records at the same time 
# to avoid specifying it in each function
names(hyacinth.data)[2:3] <- c("decimallongitude", "decimallatitude")

hyacinth.data.clean <- hyacinth.data%>%
  cc_val()%>% # invalid lat/lon coordinates
  cc_equ()%>% # records with identical lat/lon
  cc_cap()%>% # coordinates in vicinity of country capitals
  cc_cen()%>% # coordinates in vicinity of country or probince centroids
  cc_coun(iso3 = "countryCode")%>% #coordinates outside reported country
  cc_gbif()%>% # coordinates assigned to GBIF headquarters
  cc_inst()%>% # coordinates in the vicinity of biodiversity institutions (botanical gardens, universities, museums)
  cc_zero()%>% # coordinates that are zero 
  ## cc_outl()%>% # coordinates that are geographic outliers in species distribution *probably don't use this one!
  cc_dupl() # duplicate records

# coordinate uncertainty <1000m - to match spatial resolution of 1km or less
hyacinth_data_clean <- coord_uncertain(hyacinth_data_clean, coorduncertainityLimit = 1000)
nrow(hyacinth_data_clean) # leaves 1987 records

# check if there are any 'zero' individual counts through the 'table' function
table(hyacinth_data_clean$individualCount) # remove zeros (if applicable) but N/As are ok

# create map to visualize cleaning
wm <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="gray50")
ggplot()+ coord_fixed()+ wm +
  geom_point(data = hyacinth.data.clean, aes(x = decimallongitude, y = decimallatitude),
             colour = "darkred", size = 0.5)+
  theme_bw()

# plot cleaned data
plot(hyacinth.data.clean$decimallongitude, hyacinth.data.clean$decimallatitude, col = "black", 
     title("Hyacinth cleaned occurrences"))

# thin dataset to one occurrence/1km
hyacinth.thinned <- thin(hyacinth.data.clean, lat.col = "decimallatitude", 
                         long.col = "decimallongitude", spec.col = "species", 
                         thin.par = 1, reps = 1, locs.thinned.list.return = TRUE, write.files = TRUE, 
                         max.files = 1, out.dir = "C:\\...", 
                         out.base = "hyacinth.thinned") # thin par is in km

# transform from dataframe to table
library(data.table)
hyacinth.thinned <- setDT(hyacinth.thinned[[1]])

# add downscaled data
points(hyacinth.thinned$Latitude, hyacinth.thinned$Longitude, col = "red")

# load EDDMaps geopackage by layers
library(sf)
linelayer <- st_read("E:\\...\\observations.gpkg", 
                     layer = "Linelayer")
pointlayer <- st_read("E:\\...\\observations.gpkg", 
                      layer = "Pointlayer")
polygonlayer <- st_read("E:\\...\\observations.gpkg",
                        layer = "Polygonlayer")

# visualize geopackage layers
plot(pointlayer, max.plot = 1)
plot(linelayer, max.plot = 1)
plot(polygonlayer, max.plot = 1)

# remove irrelevant columns
pointlayer <- pointlayer[ , c("SciName", "OccStatus", "Status", "ObsDate", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Centroid", "CoordAcc", "Reference")]
polygonlayer <- polygonlayer[ , c("SciName", "OccStatus", "Status", "ObsDate", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Centroid", "CoordAcc", "Reference")]
linelayer <- linelayer[ , c("SciName", "OccStatus", "Status", "ObsDate", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Centroid", "CoordAcc", "Reference")]

# transform line and polygon layers into multipoint data
polygon.points <- st_cast(polygonlayer, "MULTIPOINT")
line.points <- st_cast(linelayer, "MULTIPOINT")

#visualize transformed layers
plot(polygon.points, max.plot = 1, col = "black")
plot(line.points, max.plot = 1, col = "black")

# filter N/A values
polygon.points <- polygon.points%>%
  filter(!is.na(Longitude))%>%
  filter(!is.na(Latitude))%>%
  filter(!is.na(OccStatus))%>%
  filter(!is.na(SciName))%>%
  filter(!is.na(ObsDate))%>%
  filter(Status != "Negative")
line.points <- line.points%>%
  filter(!is.na(Longitude))%>%
  filter(!is.na(Latitude))%>%
  filter(!is.na(OccStatus))%>%
  filter(!is.na(SciName))%>%
  filter(!is.na(ObsDate))%>%
  filter(Status != "Negative")
pointlayer <- pointlayer%>%
  filter(!is.na(Longitude))%>%
  filter(!is.na(Latitude))%>%
  filter(!is.na(OccStatus))%>%
  filter(!is.na(SciName))%>%
  filter(!is.na(ObsDate))%>%
  filter(Status != "Negative")  

# thin EDDMaps layers
points.thin <- thin(pointlayer, lat.col = "Latitude", 
                         long.col = "Longitude", spec.col = "SciName", 
                         thin.par = 1, reps = 1, locs.thinned.list.return = TRUE, write.files = TRUE, 
                         max.files = 1, out.dir = "C:\\...", 
                         out.base = "points.thin")
line.thin <- thin(line.points, lat.col = "Latitude", 
                  long.col = "Longitude", spec.col = "SciName", 
                  thin.par = 1, reps = 1, locs.thinned.list.return = TRUE, write.files = TRUE, 
                  max.files = 1, out.dir = "C:\\...", 
                  out.base = "line.thin")
polygon.thin <- thin(polygon.points, lat.col = "Latitude", 
                     long.col = "Longitude", spec.col = "SciName", 
                     thin.par = 1, reps = 1, locs.thinned.list.return = TRUE, write.files = TRUE, 
                     max.files = 1, out.dir = "C:\\...", 
                     out.base = "polygon.thin")
```

Comment: A guess: `thin()` doesn't like tibbles. Try `thin(as.data.frame(pointlayer), ...)`. If it works, I'll explain what's going on.

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you for a quick reply! I tried it as follows:

points.thin <- thin(as.data.frame(pointlayer), lat.col = "Latitude", 
                         long.col = "Longitude", spec.col = "SciName", 
                         thin.par = 1, reps = 1, locs.thinned.list.return = TRUE, write.files = TRUE, 
                         max.files = 1, out.dir = "C:\\...", 
                         out.base = "points.thin")

and it still gave me the same error. Did I execute it incorrectly maybe?

Comment: no, that's what I meant. If it didn't work then my idea about the problem is wrong.

Comment: All good, thank you for trying!

Comment: If you are using an R version before R 4.1.0, try setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the st_read calls.

Comment: @xilliam I'm using the most updated version of R but I tried it anyways- unfortunately, it did not work :( 
When I switched it to `= TRUE ` the function worked but my lat and long appeared as values such as 8617 and 10 so that's a bit of an issue haha.

Comment: Hmmm...a follow-up guess: Try your original data prep code, with an added line of ```line.points$SciName <- factor(line.point$SciName)```. Then try the thin() call. This should not change you long/lat values, but convert SciName to a factor, which might coax you desired result.

Comment: I got it! It was actually rather simple as all I needed to do was make it numeric haha... I should have known... I ended up doing 'EDD.points$Latitude <- as.numeric(points.thin$Latitude)
EDD.points$Longitude <- as.numeric(points.thin$Longitude)' which made it so that I didn't even have to transform the data from "sf" format.

Comment: Please **don't** post a solution by editing your question.  Instead, post an *answer* to your own question (this is allowed, and indeed encouraged).

Comment: ** SOLUTION **

I was able to solve this issue by turning my Latitude and Longitude columns into numeric variables using:

    `points.thin$Latitude <- as.numeric(points.thin$Latitude) 
    points.thin$Longitude <- as.numeric(points.thin$Longitude)`

This allowed me to thin an "sf" object without requiring a transformation to a dataframe or table.